# asp.net vbscript send message to ip and port

Tags: asp.net, tcp, vbscript, telnet

Need some advice, i am very new to asp.net so here is the scenario i am trying to create.

I know the IP Address and Port of a device, i can send a simple message such as "MMS" and the device reacts to the message.

Now i want to create a webpage that can connect to a IP by using a dropdown list because they are a few devices, but connection is 1 at a time.
What code can i use to establish the connection?

And then i want to have some buttons that will send message onclick.

Hope you can help.